# Drag parent element through the child element in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, frontend, internet-explorer-11

I have a table with rows and each row has a drag button which you can click and hold on to to make the row draggable to another position in the table. This is working fine in Chrome but not in IE11. I experimented by making the row draggable by default and I found that I can only drag the row element if I interact with it directly. If I click and drag from the button element, the row is not dragged. How can I make the parent element draggable through dragging the child element in IE11?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.droptarget {
  float: left; 
  width: 100px; 
  height: 35px;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Drag the p element back and forth between the two rectangles:</p>

<div class="droptarget">
  <div draggable="true" id="dragtarget">Drag me!
  <button>button</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="droptarget"></div>

<p style="clear:both;"><strong>Note:</strong> drag events are not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions or Safari 5.1 and earlier versions.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
/* Events fired on the drag target */

document.addEventListener("dragstart", function(event) {
  // The dataTransfer.setData() method sets the data type and the value of the dragged data
  event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", event.target.id);
  
  // Output some text when starting to drag the p element
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Started to drag the p element.";
  
  // Change the opacity of the draggable element
  event.target.style.opacity = "0.4";
});

// While dragging the p element, change the color of the output text
document.addEventListener("drag", function(event) {
  document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "red";
});

// Output some text when finished dragging the p element and reset the opacity
document.addEventListener("dragend", function(event) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Finished dragging the p element.";
  event.target.style.opacity = "1";
});

/* Events fired on the drop target */

// When the draggable p element enters the droptarget, change the DIVS's border style
document.addEventListener("dragenter", function(event) {
  if ( event.target.className == "droptarget" ) {
    event.target.style.border = "3px dotted red";
  }
});

// By default, data/elements cannot be dropped in other elements. To allow a drop, we must prevent the default handling of the element
document.addEventListener("dragover", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});

// When the draggable p element leaves the droptarget, reset the DIVS's border style
document.addEventListener("dragleave", function(event) {
  if ( event.target.className == "droptarget" ) {
    event.target.style.border = "";
  }
});

/* On drop - Prevent the browser default handling of the data (default is open as link on drop)
   Reset the color of the output text and DIV's border color
   Get the dragged data with the dataTransfer.getData() method
   The dragged data is the id of the dragged element ("drag1")
   Append the dragged element into the drop element
*/
document.addEventListener("drop", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if ( event.target.className == "droptarget" ) {
    document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "";
    event.target.style.border = "";
    var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Edit: I found that I am not able to drag the parent through the button element in IE11. I worked around this issue by not using a button, and used a div instead.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I'm not sure what code you used to implement the current feature, or what API you used. If possible, you could describe them briefly in your questions or post sample code to help us understand your requirements.

In addition, if you want to drag table row via child element in cells, you can try using [jquery UI-sorTable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/).

Here is a simple demo:

```js
$("table tbody").sortable({
            handle: 'button',
            cancel:'',
            delay: 30,
            stop: function () {
                var selectedRow = new Array();
                $('.row_drag > tr').each(function () {
                    selectedRow.push($(this).attr("id"));
                });
            }
        });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<h3>Test page</h3>
    <br />
    <table id="table" class="draggable-table" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Occupation</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody class="row_drag">
            <tr>
                <td>April Douglas</td>
                <td>Health Educator</td>
                <td style="text-align:center"><button type="button" class="dragBtn">move</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Salma Mcbride</td>
                <td>Mental Health Counselor</td>
                <td style="text-align:center"><button type="button" class="dragBtn">move</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Kassandra Donovan</td>
                <td>Makeup Artists</td>
                <td style="text-align:center"><button type="button" class="dragBtn">move</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Yosef Hartman</td>
                <td>Theatrical and Performance</td>
                <td style="text-align:center"><button type="button" class="dragBtn">move</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```